# Быстая загрузка страницы

Tags: javascript

Почему страницы на http://auto2.yandex.ru/ так быстро загружаются?

Comment: 5 секунд? Не так уж и быстро.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такие понятия как клиентская и серверная оптимизация, которые отвечают за загрузку страницы. Можно даже назвать их определёнными областями ( со всеми тонкостями и прочим ).
Обычно они включает в себя следующий перечень работ:

- Сокращение количества запросов к
     серверу. Это означает, что мы
     уменьшаем количество js и css до
     одного, объединяем картинки в так
     называемые спрайты (sprite).

  - Сами файлы html/js/css/images минимизируем по размеру ( а также,
       как уже верно подметили, правильно
       организуем код )
  - Для редко изменяющихся файлов выставляем кэширование.
  - Используем сжатие файлов (gzip-сжатие).
  - CDN, несколько хостов

Так вот, как минимум эти работы, плюс ряд других позволяют странице загружаться очень быстро.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри head там мимнимум загрузки, все скрипты грузятся внизу в body (т.е. без ожидания загрузки скриптов строится документ) + 1 скрипт в head который грузится асинхронно. Верстка таблицей. Ну это все что я увидел в firebug а так еще бы сервер посмотреть (: НУ яндекс там же гуру веб программирования работают.